# Cannot connect React to Graphene using GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, graphene-django

So create graphene query and works on GraphiQL, I'm trying to connect it to react using apollo client but I keep getting error.

On Django the error is

```
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
```

on React the error is `Error! 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`

As you can see here, it's working on `GrahiQL`

[image]

Here is my setup

URL

```
 path("graphql/", csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))),
```

SETTINGS

```
    CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
        "http://localhost:3000",
        "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        ....
    ]

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        .....
        "graphene_django",
        'corsheaders',
    ]
```

INDEX.JS

```
    import React from "react";
    import { ApolloProvider, ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

    const client = new ApolloClient({
        uri: "http://localhost:8000/graphql/",
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <App />
        </ApolloProvider>,
        document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

In EMPLOYEELIST.JS

```
    import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
    const EMP = gql`
        query getEmployees {
            allEmployees {
                id
                fullName
                isActive
                hourlyRate
                slug
                paystubData
            }
        }
    `;
    export const ListEmployee = () => {
        const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(EMP);
        if (loading) return "Loading...";
        if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
        const [records, setRecords] = useState(data.allEmployees);
        ...
        return(
             .....)
```

I tested the react component with localstorage first and everything was fine there too, now bring the two together, I'm getting this error. I don't know what I'm missing here really.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: auth/user role reasons?

Comment: What do you mean sir?

Comment: check playground request headers ... recreate request using Postman, if works compare react request, if not then data not accessible for 'external' user, auth required

Comment: Please post the resolver of all employees